# Node version not upgrading

Tags: node.js, docker, nodes, dockerfile

I am trying to upgrade the node version to meet other dependencies of my project. And I have tried  various methods to find a proper solution. But unfortunately, nothing is working. I end up trying  [this](http://tecadmin.net/upgrade-nodejs-via-npm/#)
 and no change in the response. 
My current node version is **v0.10.33**. This is actually implemented on docker. I am attaching the docker file below.

```bash
FROM node:6.2.1

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing

RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip && pip install supervisor-stdout

# Cleanup
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
RUN apt-get autoremove -y

#ADD ./config/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord- nodejs.conf

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node

ADD package.json /
ONBUILD RUN npm install

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN npm update

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
#ENTRYPOINT ["/nodejs/bin/npm", "start"]
```

Since I am not pretty good at docker and node don't what is happening. Even though docker file started with **From  node:6.2.1** the node version instaling is v0.10.33. And that is a weird thing I am experiencing. All kinda help are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `ln -s` is the wrong way around and should be failing.

```
Step 7 : RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
 ---> Running in 4f1e92a58fe8
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/node': File exists
The command '/bin/sh -c ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If you hadn't noticed this error then you would be running the old image still with node v0.10.33.

Change that line to

```
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
```

If this is part of some build scripts, always check the exit status of your commands. In bash, `$?` will give you the return code or `set -e` will automagically check return codes for you.

Comment: Thank you for the helping hand. I will give a try and let you know the comments on this.